# Creating Many-to-many relationship with repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, repository-pattern

I have a Dish and Category tables which look like that:

```
public class Dish {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserDish> UserDishes { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DishCategory> DishCategories { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class Category {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DishCategory> DishCategories { get; set; }

}
```

And I have interfaces for each of them and the implementation

```
public class EFDishRepository : IDishRepository {

    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EFDishRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx) {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    public IQueryable<Dish> Dishes => _context.Dishes;

}
```

```
public class EFCategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EFCategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx) {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    public IQueryable<Category> Categories => _context.Categories;
}
```

I'm having a many to many relationship mapped by fluent API.

My question is what is the best practice going about dealing with `DishCategory` table?

Should I create separate repository for dealing with that, cause dealing with it from either `Dish` or `Category` side just does not feel right?

Comment: Here is a small guide to the repo pattern -> https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/common-mistakes-with-the-repository-pattern/ . Returning IQueryable is *"bad"* practice in general. Also what makes sense to you? It is not wrong to have 2 domains in one repo if this is what you are asking. Make sure you let the consumer of the repo know this, since this is a more expensive query.

Comment: @panoskarajohn Should i instead do all the filtering in repository with different methods for each? I am asking if it is okey to have a joining table repository, because i couldnt find an example anywhere

Comment: It is ok to have joinin tables inside your repo. What I usually do for filtering is have a `filter of type Expression<Func<MyClass,bool>>` as a parameter and let it handle all my filtering inside the repo. Also as for your repo make sure you have seperate methods. For your example it makes sense to get all `dishes with categories` to me. I would have twho methods inside my DishRepo one called `GetAllDishes` and one called `GetAllDishesWithCategories` and I would pass the filter `Expression<Func<Dish,bool>>` to both. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @panoskarajohn It does, its just a little advanced for me, i will need to get more into delegates for sure. Maybe you have a good article or example using filters like that? anyways that answered my question, move it to answers ill accept it

Comment: I really like this -> http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx. It shows LinqKit(you do not have to use it). It showcases how the expression trees are used with Linq.

Comment: Also if you are still in doubt about your code -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ you can get a code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the best practice going about dealing with DishCategory table?

They should be in the same repository. And your `ApplicationDbContext` is a perfectly good repository.  There's no reason to wrap it in separate repository classes in the first place.

If you go down that road you'll constantly be adding and changing methods in your repository to implement business logic in your application, and your repository will end up full of code that belongs outside the repository, like queries and transactions.

If you want a single-entity repository, you should *at least* have a method to get to the DbContext to access additional Entities.  Here's an idea for a simple single-Entity interface, using C# 8's new default interface implementation feature.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    public DbSet<T> Set
    {
        get 
        {
            var db = (DbContext)this;
            return db.Set<T>();

        }
    }
    public T Find(int id)
    {
        return Set.Find(id);
    }        

    //. . .
}
```